# AWS DynamoDB Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, amazon-dynamodb

I have one dynamo table. Any data insert to a table it will trigger one lambda function. So in loop when I hit data to dynamo table. Some time trigger not happening for one or two rows

What is the solution for trigger not happening for loop

Comment: Hey Ramesh and welcome to stackoverflow! We need some configuration and/or code to help you here. A wild guess: your batch size is greater than one and you only process one event in your lambda.

Comment: Is the lambda not triggered at all, or is it triggered N times after N database insertions have been completed?

Comment: If we hit api in loop for 3 times. It will insert data to DynamoDB as 3 rows. But trigger happening only for 2 rows. Last rows trigger not happening.

Comment: Configured triggered as batchsize 100 and only for insert new record to dynamo